# How to valid 2 sticked argc in C

Tags: c, arguments, argv, argc

I'm making a very simple program code.

First, it has the option "-num" as 2nd argc. If you input anything in the 3rd argc, the program will simply say that the 3rd argc is entered.

Here are the examples of the inputs and outputs.

Input command line 1:

```
./test -num
```

Output 1

```
-num
```

Input command line 2:

```
./test -num AnythingHere
```

Output 2

```
-num 3rdArgcEntered
```

I also want the following command line with sticked argc (-num and AnythingHere are sticked together) to give the same output as Output 2:

```
./test -numAnythingHere
```

The output I wish to get is:

```
-num 3rdArgcEntered
```

But I obtained:

```
None
```

This is the source code I'm currently working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-num")) 
    {
        printf("-num ");

        if(argc==3){
            printf("3rdArgcEntered");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("None");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `getopt` and `getopt_long`  from the [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt)

Answer (score 1):

a little trash..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* doesnt check when args are not entered */
    char *tmp = argv[1];
    char buff[5];
    /* copy -num, doesnt check */
    memcpy(buff, tmp, 4);
    buff[4] = '\0';

    if (!strcmp(buff, "-num")) 
    {
        printf("-num ");

        /* larger than -num */
        if(argc==3 || strlen(tmp) > 4 ){
        printf("3rdArgcEntered");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         printf("None");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program can't affect how the arguments are passed; obviously `main` has already been called at the beginning of `main`. You need to parse each argument yourself, or use a library that does it for you. For parsing them yourself, you could look at `strtok` or `sscanf`, or iterate over the characters. But a more specific library, such as `getopt`, is generally preferable, since it makes it easy to get your program to behave in a manner consistent with other command-line utilities.